# Stability of time stepping in PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, stability-in-odes

I am currently trying to perform a stability assessment on solving a parabolic PDE of the form
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = g(x,t) \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + u
$$
I am using Crank-Nicolson in space and just forward Euler in time. I know that to assess stability, we write the PDE in the form
$$
u^{n+1} = A \cdot u^n + f
$$
and check to see if the eigenvalues of $A$ are less than 1. Now, if the matrix $A$ varies in time, would this assessment need to be performed at each time step? I am doing this in order to bound my time step.

Comment: @GBV When we speak of Crank-Nicolson, it is already the space-time discretization. The semi-discretization in space with (centered) finite-differences, and the numerical solution of the resulting system of ODEs using the trapezoidal rule.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the clarification! In which case, the method is unconditionally stable. Correct?